# Sum of principal minors of order $n-1$ equals the sum of products of eigen values taken $n-1$ at a time

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix of order $n$ .Prove that

> Sum of principal minors of  $A$  of order $n-1$ equals the sum of products of eigen values taken $n-1$ at a time .

Now if I consider the characteristic polynomial of $A$ say $a_0+a_1X+\ldots +a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+a_nX^n$, then sum of products of eigen values taken $n-1$ at a time will be given by $\dfrac{a_{n-1}}{a_0}$.

But how to link this expression to the sum of principal minors of $A$.

Please help how to show  this.

Comment: the characteristic polynomial of $P^{-1}AP$ is the same as the characteristic polynomial of $A.$ This includes when $P^{-1}AP$ is in Jordan form.